# Samba share to windows XP

Tags: samba

I have a samba share in 14.04.3 LTS that's accessed by some windows computer. The share is basically working, because I can access files from both platforms in "all directions". However I have a script that fetches information in Linux and writes information to file in this share. (always the same name of the file). In windows there is a .vbs script that reads the information in the file. For some reason the script in windows doesn't get the latest information.
There is also the issue with the explorer as discussed in this thread:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2261091

The size and file in windows explorer doesn't update, it updates perfectly when files are deleted and created, but updating the same file is a problem.

If I in windows opens the file with notepad then it always fetches the latest information, with this action also the script reads the updated version of the file.

The same setup was working with 10.04, but after the upgrade of Linux to 14.04 something got broken.
Any ideas where to look for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> However I have a script that fetches information in Linux and writes information to file in this share.

After writing the file, before your .VBS program reads it, flush the file buffer manually. I don't know how to do that in a shell script, but in perl you close the filehandle:

```
close($FILE);
```